# Limit of two variables depending on $a>0$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \geq 2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to calculate the following limit:
$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,a)}\frac{(x-y)a^n+(a-x)y^n-(a-y)x^n}{(x-y)(a-x)(a-y)}$.
I have tried to do the change of variables $x-a=z$ and $y-a=t$ to evaluate the same limit but as $(z,t)$ approaches $(0,0)$ and the limit about the curve $z=2t$ has given me $\frac{n(n-1)a^{n-2}}{2}$ (so, if the limit exists, this would be its value). I have tried to approach with other curves and they also result in that value for the limit; so my intuition says that it exists but I don't know how to prove it. Thanks.

Comment: The answer looks like a second derivative of something, so I'm tempted to try to interpret the original function in the context of the definition of the derivative or to use the mean value theorem or something....